# Multiply floats from two separate lists in Python

Tags: python, list, loops, iterator

In my code I have two separate lists. I would like to multiply the value of list[0] by list2[0], list[1] by list2[1] and so on.

```
value = []
quantity = []

for line in fh:
    if line.startswith("Value"):
        line = line[18:len(line)]
        line = float(line)
        value.append(line)

for line2 in fh:
    if line2.startswith("Amount"):
        line2 = line2[17:len(line2)]
        line2 = float(line2)
        quantity.append(line2)
```

First I am experiencing a "list index out of range" for my 'quantity' list. Why is that?

To then multiply would something like this work?

```
total = 0.0
temp = 0.0

for i in range(len(value))
    temp = value[i]*quantity[i]
    total = total + temp
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can `zip` the lists together, than iterate over the pairs and multiply them. Then `sum` the resulting list.

```
total = sum([val * quant for val, quant in zip(value, quantity)])
```

For example

```
>>> value = [2,1,5,3,6]
>>> quantity = [2,1,0,6,2]
>>> total = sum([val * quant for val, quant in zip(value, quantity)])
>>> total
35
```

Comment: If the two lists are not the same length, `itertools.izip_longest` may be better.

Comment: Wow. You guys are awesome. Zip seemed to work perfectly. Thanks a ton, I really appreciate it.

Comment: @squiguy no ... not unless you expect the behaviour defined by Padraic Cunningham above

Comment: @JoranBeasley I see. That's the exact reason I put that comment. But in this case, zip is perfectly fine.

Answer (score 3):

Use itertools.izip_longest with a `fillvalue` of `1`, if the lists are not the same length you will  multiply the elements of the longest list by 1.

```
from itertools import izip_longest

l1 = [1,2,3,4]
l2 = [1,2,3,4,5]
print([x*y for x,y in (izip_longest(l1,l2,fillvalue=1))])
[1, 4, 9, 16, 5]
```

Comment: (+1)this is the case where you might want izip_longest... since he didnt define what he expects when lists are not same length

Answer (score 1):

You iterate through `fh` twice, but the first iteration exhausts the file, and any subsequent iterations will yield no values. Consequently, `quantity` will never get appended to. If you want to un-exhaust the file, try seeking back to the beginning.

```
fh.seek(0)
for line2 in fh:
    #...
```

---

Edit: or just put the second `if` block in the first loop.

```
for line in fh:
    if line.startswith("Value"):
        line = line[18:len(line)]
        line = float(line)
        value.append(line)
    else if line2.startswith("Amount"):
        line = line[17:len(line)]
        line = float(line)
        quantity.append(line)
```

Comment: Or more simply put the second ```if``` block in the first loop